# Unknown error in a C++ program

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, stl, iterator

```
void change_degree(vector<int> &nodes, map<int, vector<int> > &edges, int vertex){
    map<int, vector<int> >::iterator ite;
    ite = edges.find(vertex);
    vector<int> temp = (*ite).second;
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    for(it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); it++){
        cout << *it;
        if(nodes[*it + 1] > 1)
            nodes[*it + 1]++;
    }
}
```

This function is producing error

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x09c930e0 ***
```

Can someone tell me why is it coming and what it means? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to `vertex` not being in `edges`? If not, the only possible invalid access in that function is `nodes[*it + 1]`.

Comment: `gdb` and `valgrind` said hi!

Comment: Vertex is present edges.

Comment: It probably means there's memory abuse going on, and something is being freed that was not allocated, or thereabouts.  Use `valgrind` to locate the problem if it is available.  Look at the manual pages for `malloc()` to see what debugging options you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one issue I see is that you're not checking to see if `vertex` was actually found in `edges`. You are probably dereferencing memory you don't own.

```
void change_degree(vector<int> &nodes, map<int, vector<int> > &edges, int vertex){
    map<int, vector<int> >::iterator ite = edges.find(vertex);
    if (ite != edges.end()) {  // <-- this is what you're missing
        vector<int> temp = (*ite).second;  // <-- this is probably where you're dying
        vector<int>::iterator it;
        for(it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); it++){
            cout << *it;
            if(nodes[*it + 1] > 1)  // <-- you could also be crashing here
                nodes[*it + 1]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Next time, try running your app through GDB, and check your stack trace.

Edit: another possibility is that you're indexing into `nodes` incorrectly. Check that `nodes[*it + 1]` is valid.

Comment: As I wrote in comments, vertex is present in edges and even after checking the condition ite != edges.end(), it is giving the same error

Comment: thanks it was giving because of nodes[*it + 1]. Thanks @moswald